# How can I get two columns in a subquery using top 1?

Tags: sql, database, join, subquery, amazon-redshift

Here's the thing. I have these two tables:

table A:

```
id    col1    date_x
A     xxxx    2020-02-02
B     yyyy    2020-02-02
C     zzzz    2020-02-02
```

table B

```
id    col2    date_y
A     yyyy    2020-01-02
A     yyyy    2020-02-02
A     yyyy    2020-03-02
```

I wanted to bring col2 when date_y is the highest possible but it has to be lower than date_x.

This is what I've done:

```
select *,
       (
         select top 1 col2
         from table_B
         where table_B.date_y < a.date_x 
         and table_B.id = a.id
       ) as col2                   
from table_A a
```

Now, I wanted to bring date_y as well, in order to do some validation.

What is the best way of doing this? I thought about creating another (select top 1...) but this seems very inefficient. Another join would also be inefficient.

Comment: Well, I didn't face any error. @a_horse_with_no_name, not sure how postgresql interpreted the "top" there, but the code ran just fine

Comment: That's Amazon Redshift, not PostgreSQL. Although they share some ancient common roots, they are substantially different products

Comment: sorry, still new at this

Answer (score 1):

You can join the tables on your conditions and use `MAX()` and `FIRST_VALUE()` window functions to get the `date_y` and `col2` values:

```
select distinct a.*,
       first_value(b.col2) over (partition by a.id order by b.date_y desc, b.col2) col2,
       max(b.date_y) over (partition by a.id) date_y
from tableA a left join tableB b
on b.id = a.id and b.date_y < a.date_x
```

You may change the `LEFT` join to an `INNER` join if you want only matched rows from the 2 tables.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4d6zM6P6yRKTaRFGXJzxsU/1).

Comment: got the error: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause;

Comment: Do you have duplicate dates for the same id in tabl B?

Comment: It might be possible

Comment: In that case, if that highest possible date_y can be found in more than 1 rows which value of col2 do you want?

Comment: @DumbML is there a reason that you unaccepted the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach using a correlated subquery is OK - and Redshift supports `top` (although I prefer `limit`, that is more widely supported in other databases).

However you are missing an `order by` clause in the subquery - without it, you get an unpredictable row out of those that satisfy the `where` clause, which is not what you want.

I would recommend:

```
select 
    a.*,
    (
        select col2
        from table_B b
        where b.date_y < a.date_x and b.id = a.id
        order by b.date_y desc
        limit 1
    ) as col2                   
 from table_A a
```

For performance, consider an index on `table_B(id, date_y, col2)`.